# CSV file duplicate header row

Tags: shell, csv, unix

I want to copy/duplicate the first row of a CSV file. The first row is the header row that contains the name of columns. Is there any bash or shell command to do this? I researched on the internet, but, was not able to find anything helpful.

Input CSV:

```
column_A, column_B, column_C
1, 2, 3
4, 5, 6
7, 8, 9
```

Output CSV:

```
column_A, column_B, column_C
column_A, column_B, column_C
1, 2, 3
4, 5, 6
7, 8, 9
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is duplicate the first line, then the following might do the trick:

```
sed 1p input.csv
```